# Shipping products with DHL dimensions

Tags: shipping, magento-2.1, dhl

I have a question about how shipping costs are calculated in magento 2. Don't I need to specify product dimensions somewhere? I am selling some quite large yet light items. How does the DHL connection work and how can I accurately charge the right amount of shipping fees?

Comment: Maybe this will be included in the new extension they are currently developing...